# As a non-EU citizen, can a German company hire me in Brussels? and can I do occasional (1-2 day) missions in NL, FR, DE, etc?

Tags: work-permit

I'm currently living in Belgium with student permit.

I found a job at a German company with no offices in Belgium (yet)
While the work is mostly in BE, sometimes, the work requires 1-2 day missions in NL, FR, etc.

What should I do?

It's a small company, so they don't know either.

Comment: Are you planning on doing this work alongside your studies, or have you finished your course?

Comment: @Traveller Yes for the next two months since I have my residency permit, fulltime after I get my single permit